# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 When using Magento Search

Tags: magento-1.7, database, sql

We have encountered a big problem with Magento search since this morning. When some (not all) terms are searched for we get an SQL error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

I don't know if this is relevant but the error only seems to occur when a term which is from one of the products added yesterday (the SKU, part of the product name etc.).

I've tried reindexing but it's made no difference.

The trace reads:

```
Trace:
#0 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('select count(*)...', Array)
#4 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('select count(*)...', Array)
#5 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(825): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('select count(*)...', Array)
#6 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product.php(493): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne('select count(*)...')
#7 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/app/design/frontend/bdc/responsive/template/catalog/product/list.phtml(127): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product->getTierPriceCount(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product))
#8 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/cloudpane...')
#9 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/bdc/re...')
#10 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#11 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#12 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#13 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('search_result_l...', true)
#14 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Block/Result.php(161): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('search_result_l...')
#15 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/app/design/frontend/bdc/responsive/template/catalogsearch/result.phtml(82): Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Result->getProductListHtml()
#16 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/cloudpane...')
#17 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/bdc/re...')
#18 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#19 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#20 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#21 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#22 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#23 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#24 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/app/design/frontend/bdc/responsive/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(50): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#25 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/cloudpane...')
#26 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/bdc/re...')
#27 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#28 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#29 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#30 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/app/code/local/ClickTale/Integration/Model/Layout.php(49): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#31 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(389): ClickTale_Integration_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#32 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/app/code/local/BDC/SearchRedirects/controllers/ResultController.php(81): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#33 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(417): BDC_SearchRedirects_ResultController->indexAction()
#34 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#35 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#36 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#37 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#38 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.oursite.co.uk/index.php(100): Mage::run('base', 'website')
#39 {main}
```

If anyone could point us in the right direction it'd be a massive help.

Comment: If its nothing you have changed it could be a problem with the MYSQL service on your environment, are you with a dedicated hosting company? Is this something they can look into? Maybe the service requires a restart.

Comment: You need to get the SQL being generated, either log it in mysql for a few seconds or do one of these: https://magentotherightway.com/#debugging-database-queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions.

We tried restarting SQL but that had no effect.

What we did find was that the products had been added incorrectly; the associated products had been given the visibility 'Catalog/Search' rather than 'Not Visible Individually'. It was a new-starter who added them.

So it was as simple as that. Thanks for the responses though!